# Run sql script from jpa-hibernate ddl auto

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

Can't find a solution in SO, so I'm trying to findout how to accomplish the goal here.
I've a SqlServer 2014 db which accepts and runs fine a script (which does lots of things, mainly check if exist procedures, drop then, build them, run them and drop them... ).

For example this simple statement:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID ( 'InitializeProc', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE InitializeProc ;  
GO
```

Gives me:

> HHH000388: Unsuccessful: IF OBJECT_ID ( 'InitializeProc', 'P' ) IS NOT
>   NULL ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 267) Incorrect syntax near 'NULL'.

I've tried to run my script in the create ddl-auto phase declared in persistence.xml and the sql driver in Hibernate declarations is "SQLServer2012Dialect".

I'm on Java 1.8 - Jboss 7 EAP and jpa 2.1 environment.
I've already replace End of line "LF" with "CRLF".
Since the script is very long I'm trying to figure out this problem hoping this could be the key to solve whole case.

I know I can simple call the Drop but first of all is ugly and second I found same problem for the rest in other occasions such as "AS", "GO"...an so on.

thanks!

EDIT: If I put all the statement in a single line worked. But It is really ugly to oblige developer to do that.
Tried also this in persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor" value="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor" />
```

...but:

> Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlStatementParser$StatementParserException:
>   line 1:129956: expecting STMT_END, found 'null'

Can't believe such a simple thing can't be done easily. There must be a way.

Comment: maybe Hibernate doesn't support lines that include CR? i.e all is processed line by line? The JPA provider I use works fine on such lines that wrap, since it removes all special chars, but I seem to remember hearing people in the past say either Hibernate or EclipseLink had this limitation.

Comment: Yes maybe. I found this problem with my script which shows EOL with simple "LF". Since I'm in Windows environment I replaced with "CRLF" but the behaviour is almost the same.

Comment: Raise a bug on the JPA provider you have chosen to use to support executing scripts properly rather than feeding them in line-by-line. Other JPA providers (e.g DataNucleus JPA) treat such things correctly.

Comment: It's actually unbelievable how hbm2ddl schema import is still in such an unusable state after all the years Hibernate exists...

Comment: After lots of researches I can confirm that the import works only on inline statements. When I got time I'll track the exact doc page and I'll put here. Unbelievable but that's actually the truth.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for necroposting, but I've got the same error with MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor ( expecting STMT_END, found 'null') and found the way to solve it - last statement should be ended with ; without exceptions for any kind of delimiters or comments.

Seems like a bug for 5.3.1.Final